# how to extract definitions from akka http route

Tags: routes, akka, akka-http

route definitions:

```
 val route =
  path("order" / "get") {
    get {
      parameter('id.as[String], 'name.as[String]) {
        (id, name) => {
          complete(s"""{\"path\":\"order\",\"method\":\"GET\",\"id\":$id}""")
        }
      }
    } ~
      post {
        decodeRequestWith(Gzip) {
          complete("Received POST")
        }
      }
  } ~
    path("detail") {
      get {
        complete("detail")
      }
    }

val bindingFuture = akka.http.scaladsl.Http().bindAndHandle(route, "0.0.0.0", 91)
```

I wonder to know how to get paths, parameters, methods from object route dynamic.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, so it's difficult to help. What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: Get definitions from route object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not really possible to introspect a directive tree as a lot of the logic in the tree is actually functions rather than some form of regular objects with properties and those are quite opaque. It is possible you could get some stuff out with reflection, but there is nothing out of the box in Akka HTTP.

Comment: I'll reflect it, since directive not maintain metadata, thanks.

Comment: I'll reflect it, since directive not maintain metadata, thanks.